# Multiple type custom arraylist

Tags: java, class, oop, arraylist, casting

I currently am trying to make a simple RPG-ish game. I want monsters to spawn randomly on the map. I have it set up so that when I want one to spawn it is added to an `ArrayList` called `monsters`. I will be having many different types of `monsters` by the time I am done, and each one has its own class (ex. Zombie, Ghost...) each class will have a method to draw the monster called draw. I want to know how I can do this.

`Monsters` is an `ArrayList<Object>` so it will be able to have the different classes in it, but It won't let my do `Monsters.get(i).draw()`; Is this actually possible, or am I being stupid.

Comment: Create an interface called `Monster` with every method that _every_ monster type should have and then declare your list as `List<Monster> monsters`.

Comment: Is it a typed ArrayList? Do the monster classes share a base Monster class with a draw method?

Comment: If you post some of your actual code, even if it doesn't work properly, it will be very helpful.

Comment: @Tom: It wasn't OP that wrote that (I explained that in my edit comments).  It was edited in.  So I took it out to not give the wrong impression to those reading the question that OP had coded it that way.  We don't actually know what OP's code looks like.

Comment: @Tom: Ah, I see what you are saying now.  Mea culpa! I rolled it back.

Comment: @sstan That's the problem about generic types in Java, they look like HTML tags if you don't format it. That is why it was "hidden" or not printed correctly. Btw: I often switch between "side-by-side" and "side-by-side markdown" during reviews, because "side-by-side markdown" can make it easier to determine what the change really was. :) ... (wow the grammar of the last sentence looks bad :D)

Answer (score 3):

You failed to cast the object `ArrayList<Object>` back to Monster

```
// Monster.get(i)            == Object
// (Monster) Monsters.get(i) == Monster

// cast the list item i from Object to Monster
((Monster) Monsters.get(i)).draw();
```

A better solution:

```
interface Monster {
   void draw();
}

// implement draw on each
class Zombie implements Monster {}
class Ghost implements Monster {}

ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>();
// legal
monsters.add(new Zombie());
monsters.add(new Ghost());

// legal
monsters.get(i).draw();
```

You can go with class -> extends solution or this interface -> implements. Either way this is a very bare bones example of a better way to implement your Monsters.

Comment: much better to use an interface without the need of typecasts

Comment: *"You failed to unbox the object"* is "unbox" the correct word here? Isn't "cast" more correct, since "unbox" is more likely about un-/boxing primitve types to their wrapper type?

Comment: @Tom yep, I revised it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, first you need to create an interface, like `IMonster` which contains a `draw` method. Then, have each monster type implement this interface.

Your `ArrayList` will look like this:

```
List<IMonster> monsters = new ArrayList<IMonster>();

monsters.add(new Ghost());
monsters.add(new Goblin());
```

So here is an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Monsters {
    private static List<IMonster> monsters = new ArrayList<IMonster>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        monsters.add(new Ghost());
        monsters.add(new Goblin());
        monsters.add(new Devil());  

        for (IMonster monster : monsters) {
            monster.draw();
        }
    }
}

interface IMonster {
    public void draw();
}

abstract class AbstractMonster implements IMonster {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Shared drawing code for all monsters");
    } 
}

class Ghost extends AbstractMonster {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        System.out.println("Ghost drawing code");
    }
}

class Goblin extends AbstractMonster {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        System.out.println("Goblin drawing code");
    }
}

class Devil extends AbstractMonster {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        System.out.println("Devil drawing code");
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to actually have a variable name in your statement. :)

Comment: And try to always use Interfaces for variable types, so `List<IMonster>` instead of `ArrayList<IMonster>`.

Comment: If there is common drawing code, each subtype may decide to call its superclass's draw method first. The subtype may also elect to do its own drawing altogether in which case you don't call super.draw() at all...

Comment: @Constantin Please mind that I've added the missing annotation `@Override` to your `draw` implementations. This always a very good idea to do that to enable compiler checks. If you don't like them, then either you or I can remove them. Btw: you might want to rethink that `new("Ghost")`, because this is no valid Java code :P.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I changed it. I ran the code and it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast your item get from the ArrayList like this -

```
Object item = Monsters.get(i);
Monster monster = (Monster) item;
monster.draw();
```

Or better you may use some Interface. You may use an interface (for example `Drawable` ). Your `Monster`and other drawable class would implement it. Then use the `ArrayList` of `Drawable`.

```
interface Drawable{
   public void draw();
} 

public class Monster implements Drawable {

   public void draw(){
      //implementation of monster's draw
   } 
} 
...
... 

ArrayList<Drawable> monsters = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
...
...
monsters.get(i).draw();
```